# Will there be an earthquake?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've built a small utility in Python which is going to *supposedly* send an SMS (using [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/)) each time an earthquake with the magnitude > 4 is to be happening.

> **NOTE:**
>
> This simple script was mainly done for testing purposes and learning
>   activities. **DO NOT** take the information for granted as there might
>   be big delays between the time the earthquake occurs and the time the
>   SMS arrives.
>
> More, this works only for *Romania, Europe* and it's using the data
>   from [this website](http://alerta.infp.ro) which is in a testing phase
>   (BETA).

This should eventually run as a daemon on a UNIX OS.

I'd like to receive any kind of feedback regarding this and what could possibly be improved.

```py
"""
This projects aims to send an SMS to a specific number using Twilio
if an earthquake with magnitude > 4 is going to occur (depending on
your location, this can warn you (best case scenario within 25-30
seconds before you feel the earthquake wave).
"""

import datetime
import json
import re
import time

import requests

from exceptions import EmptyCredentialsFile

from lxml.html import fromstring
from twilio.rest import Client


BASE_URL = 'http://alerta.infp.ro'
DATA_URL = f'{BASE_URL}/server.php'
CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'credentials.json'
DELAY = 1  # seconds


def read_credentials_file(filepath: str) -> dict:
    """Return secrets from `credentials_file` file as a dict.

    The file looks like this:

        {
          "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID": "Your twilio account SID",
          "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN": "Your twilio account auth token",
          "FROM": "The number from which you'll receive the alert",
          "TO": "The number the message is sent to"
        }


    Args:
        filepath (str): Path to credentials JSON file.

    Returns:
        dict: The return value.
    """

    with open(filepath) as credentials_file:
        credentials = json.load(credentials_file)

    if not credentials:
        raise EmptyCredentialsFile('Credentials file should not be empty.')

    return credentials


def get_credential(name: str) -> str:
    """Return a specific credential value based on its name.

    Args:
        name (str): Name of the desired credential

    Returns:
        str: The return value
    """

    credentials = read_credentials_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE)
    return credentials.get(name)


def get_earthquake_data() -> dict:
    """Get earthquake data from `DATA_URL`.

    Returns:
        dict: A dict containing the following data:
              {
                'mag': '0.1',
                'heart': '2020-01-04 13:30:04 HEARTBEAT',
                'sec': '30',
                'key': 'NjY2NDYyMzAzNjMwNjM2MzM1Mz...=='
              }
    """

    session = requests.Session()
    with session as page_session:
        html_page = page_session.get(BASE_URL).content
        html_script = fromstring(html_page).xpath('//script[contains(., "source")]/text()')[0]
        key = {
            'keyto': re.search(
                r"var source = new EventSource\('server\.php\?keyto=(.*)'\);", html_script
            ).group(1)
        }
        earthquake_data = page_session.get(f'{DATA_URL}', params=key).content
        earthquake_data = earthquake_data.decode('utf8').replace("data", '"data"').strip()
        return json.loads(f'{{{earthquake_data}}}')


def send_message() -> None:
    """Send a message via Twilio if the magnitude of an earthquake
    is bigger than 4.
    """

    twilio_client = Client(
        get_credential('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'),
        get_credential('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
    )

    data = get_earthquake_data().get('data')
    eq_magnitude = data.get('mag')

    if float(eq_magnitude) >= 4:
        body = f"""ATTENTION!!!

        Earthquake with magnitude: {eq_magnitude} 
        at {datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}!
        """

        try:
            twilio_client.messages.create(
                body=body,
                from_=get_credential('FROM'),
                to=get_credential('TO')
            )
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'Twilio API error: {error}')
    else:
        print('No need to worry. YET!')


def main() -> None:
    """Main entry to the program."""

    while True:
        try:
            send_message()
            time.sleep(DELAY)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Closing the program...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the custom exception from `exceptions.py` looks like this:

```py
"""
Main module for all the exceptions across project.
"""


class EmptyCredentialsFile(Exception):
    """
    Exception to be raised when credentials file is empty and valid
    """
    pass
```

> **NOTE 2:**
>
> If you'd like to run the whole script and don't have a Twilio account,
>   just call `get_earthquake_data()` instead of `send_message()`
>   function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't really see much that's notable. This is some nice looking code.

Minor things though:

If you're going to use type-hints, I think I'd take it a step further and use the generic `Dict` to specify what types the dictionaries hold:

```
from typing import Dict

. . .

def get_earthquake_data() -> Dict[str, str]:
   . . .
```

And then similarly for the other cases. `dict` (currently?) doesn't support generic type hints, so `Dict`, a generic type alias, can be used. Now, for example:

```
data = get_earthquake_data()
val = data[some_key]  # It can typecheck the key now
val  # And it knows that this is a String
```

That also better communicates to the reader what types are involved.

---

I'm on my phone so it's a pain to check, but here:

```
except Exception as error: 
    print(f'Twilio API error: {error}')
```

Is there really not a more specific exception that Twilio throws? I'd see if it has its own base class that you can catch. You don't want to accidentally catch a non-API error there and mask a bug.

---

```
data = get_earthquake_data().get('data')
eq_magnitude = data.get('mag')
```

I'd probably use subscripting there instead of `get`. Sure, that will allow for a `KeyError`, but that will cause a more sensical error than it will if `None` is returned by `get` and you end up with `float(None)`. I only use `get` if I'm expecting a potentially invalid key and I want to handle it by checking the return for `None` (or a sentinal that I specify). I think avoiding the `KeyError` like this causes more issues than it solves by allowing bad data to be passed on instead of just dying where the error happened.

Comment: Nice answer! +1. Those are all things that I've given a thought but didn't really do anything about it. What can you say about the naming? For me (and probably most developers) that's the hardest thing ^_^

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex. No complaints they're all PEP8 compliant and descriptive.

Answer (score 4):

In your main loop, you catch `KeyBoardInterrupt` without handling it or exiting, so if you press `Ctrl-C` during execution it prints the message and continues looping forever. You should add a `break` statement after the print statement to get out of this.

Comment: Oupsiee, fair enough ^_^ That's why I love CR. Haven't even spotted something that obvious.

Answer (score 3):

> **NOTE 2:**
>
> If you'd like to run the whole script and don't have a Twilio account, just call `get_earthquake_data()` instead of `send_message()` function.

You could improve this part by providing a command line option, so that

```
python eatrhquake.py
```

Would run `get_earthquake_data()`;

```
python earthquake.py --twilio
```

Would run `send_message()` with the default (credentials.json) file; and

```
python earthquake.py --twilio /path/to/my/credentials.json
```

Would run `send_message()` with a user provided file path.

---

Python provides the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module for such case that you can define along the lines of

```
def command_line_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Earthquake Listener')
    parser.add_argument(
            '-t', '--twilio',
            nargs='?',
            type=argparse.FileType('r'),
            const='credentials.json',
            help='<describe the file and its content here>')
    return parser
```

You can then use `parser.parse_args().twilio` to know which function to call depending on wether it is `None` or an opened file object.

---

You also call `get_credentials()` a lot during the script lifetime, when you could call it only once and store the resulting dict in a variable instead. This is especially wasteful as it opens the file each time.

In the same vein, you create a Twilio client at each loop even if you don't send anything. Art the very least you could create it only when you need to send something; at best you could create it once at the beginning of the script and reuse the same for each send, but I'm not familiar with the API and there may be some timeouts limiting this option.

---

Proposed improvements:

```
"""
This projects aims to send an SMS to a specific number using Twilio
if an earthquake with magnitude > 4 is going to occur (depending on
your location, this can warn you (best case scenario within 25-30
seconds before you feel the earthquake wave).
"""

import argparse
import datetime
import json
import re
import time
from functools import partial

import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from twilio.rest import Client


BASE_URL = 'http://alerta.infp.ro'
DATA_URL = f'{BASE_URL}/server.php'


def command_line_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Earthquake Listener')
    parser.add_argument(
            '-t', '--twilio',
            nargs='?',
            type=credentials,
            const='credentials.json',
            help='<???>')
    parser.add_argument(
            '-d', '--delay',
            type=float,
            default=1.0,
            help='delay in seconds between two calls to the earthquake API')
    return parser


def credentials(filepath: str) -> dict:
    """Return secrets from `filepath` file as a dict.

    The file looks like this:

        {
          "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID": "Your twilio account SID",
          "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN": "Your twilio account auth token",
          "FROM": "The number from which you'll receive the alert",
          "TO": "The number the message is sent to"
        }


    Args:
        filepath (str): Path to credentials JSON file.

    Returns:
        dict: The return value.
    """

    with open(filepath) as credentials_file:
        credentials = json.load(credentials_file)

    if not credentials:
        raise ValueError('Credentials file should not be empty.')

    return credentials


def get_earthquake_data() -> dict:
    """Get earthquake data from `DATA_URL`.

    Returns:
        dict: A dict containing the following data:
              {
                'mag': '0.1',
                'heart': '2020-01-04 13:30:04 HEARTBEAT',
                'sec': '30',
                'key': 'NjY2NDYyMzAzNjMwNjM2MzM1Mz...=='
              }
    """

    session = requests.Session()
    with session as page_session:
        html_page = page_session.get(BASE_URL).content
        html_script = fromstring(html_page).xpath('//script[contains(., "source")]/text()')[0]
        key = {
            'keyto': re.search(
                r"var source = new EventSource\('server\.php\?keyto=(.*)'\);", html_script
            ).group(1)
        }
        earthquake_data = page_session.get(f'{DATA_URL}', params=key).content
        earthquake_data = earthquake_data.decode('utf8').replace("data", '"data"').strip()
        return json.loads(f'{{{earthquake_data}}}')


def send_message(twilio_client, send_to, sent_from) -> None:
    """Send a message via Twilio if the magnitude of an earthquake
    is bigger than 4.
    """

    data = get_earthquake_data().get('data')
    eq_magnitude = data.get('mag')

    if float(eq_magnitude) >= 4:
        body = f"""ATTENTION!!!

        Earthquake with magnitude: {eq_magnitude} 
        at {datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}!
        """

        try:
            twilio_client.messages.create(body=body, from_=sent_from, to=send_to)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'Twilio API error: {error}')
    else:
        print('No need to worry. YET!')


def main(credentials=None, delay=1.0) -> None:
    """Main entry to the program."""

    if credentials is None:
        action = get_earthquake_data
    else:
        twilio_client = Client(
                credentials['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'],
                credentials['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
        sender = credentials['FROM']
        receiver = credentials['TO']
        action = partial(send_message, twilio_client, receiver, sender)

    while True:
        try:
            action()
            time.sleep(delay)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Closing the program...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = command_line_parser.parse_args()
    main(args.twilio, args.delay)
```

Note that I changed your custom exception to a `ValueError` to integrate better with `argparse`'s exception handling.